# Custom pandas sort function

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to add a function for the sort? For example:

```
df = df.groupby('path_md5').agg(agg_dict).sort_values(
    by = lambda row: (row['file_name'], -row['size'])
).reset_index()
```

Or do I need to create a new field and then sort on that field? The best I could find is something like this -- https://gist.github.com/hellpanderrr/599bce82ecc6934aa9e1.

Comment: Probably not for any function, but your code can be `.sort_values(['file_name', 'size'], ascending=[True, False])`.

Comment: @QuangHoang I see -- would you want to post an answer showing that version and then the version of using a function (or a new column) to accomplish the same, and I'll go ahead and accept it?

Comment: Sinces pandas 1.1.0 (so very recent) you can also use parameter key, for example like this: .sort_values(by='col4', key=lambda col: col.str.lower()), but I think in your case you don't need this, and Quang Hoang's answer is appropriate. See also the sort_values docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html